# using amcharts to create a line graph but nothings getting displayed

Tags: php, json, amcharts

I am trying to display a line graph . Where the y-axis contains readings and the x-axis are all the months in a year. 
links used :

```
<link href="dashboard/css/otherstyles.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="amcharts/export.css" type="text/css">
<script src="amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="amcharts/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

code that retrieves values from the database

```
function getbloodpressuredetails($id) {
    global $conn;
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT para_date, para_time, reading, type  FROM `tracking_para`  where $id = ? and para_id = 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($para_date, $para_time, $reading, $type);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $rows[] = array('para_date' => $para_date, 'para_time' => $para_time, 'reading' => $reading, 'type' => $type);
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return $rows;
    } else {
        printf("Error message: %s\n", $conn->error);
    }
}
```

using sessions getting values for that

```
<?php $blood_pressure = getbloodpressuredetails($_SESSION['id']);?>
```

script code that enables the graph . This is the part which im not sure on how it works. Nothings getting displayed on the screen . please help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
AmCharts.loadJSON = function(url) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        var request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    // load it
    // the last "false" parameter ensures that our code will wait before the
    // data is loaded
    request.open('GET', url, false);
    request.send();

    // parse and return the output
    return eval(request.responseText);
};
</script>

<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>

<!-- the chart code -->
<script>
var chart;
// create chart
AmCharts.ready(function() {
    // load the data
    var chartData = AmCharts.loadJSON('$blood_pressure');

    // SERIAL CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.pathToImages = "amcharts/images";
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "para_date";
    chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";

    // GRAPHS
    var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph1.valueField = "reading";
    graph1.bullet = "round";
    graph1.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
    graph1.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
    graph1.lineThickness = 2;
    graph1.lineAlpha = 0.5;
    chart.addGraph(graph1);

    // CATEGORY AXIS
    chart.categoryAxis.parseDates = true;

    // WRITE
    chart.write("chartdiv");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get any any errors in the browser debugger? Also, have you validated your SQL query returns data?

Comment: no i dont get any errors its just a blank page and yes my query returns data .

Comment: Something is breaking. Use a debugger/console like Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to see what the console outputs to you. Most likely throwing an error that will be very helpful.

Comment: Also, loadJSON('$blood_pressure') won't work. You have to put <?php echo $blood_pressure; ?> there for that to work (assuming blood_pressure is a Json string.

Comment: Is "$blood_pressure" even a valid URL? Your code is supposed to load JSON data from a remote URL, and you seem to be loading it from "$blood_pressure". Try changing it to some real URL to a PHP script which returns JSON data. Also take a look at this tutorial (it will probably save you a lot of time): https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/using-data-loader-to-connect-charts-to-mysql-data-base/

Comment: Blood pressure is a variable that contains the result retrieved from the database . oh I didn't notice that before, I'll change it and try it out . Ive tried the tutorial before , didn't really help